# SymPy prints function names instead of its value

Tags: python, sympy

I recently started learning IPython. I have a problem with Sympy library. It only prints the function instead of exact value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as nm
from sympy import *

x,y = symbols("x y")

expr = cos(x)
a = expr.subs(x,1)
print(a)
```

The output of above program is `cos(1)`. But I want to print the exact value of cos(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all some nitpicking: “cos(1)” is the most concise way to represent the exact value of cos(1). Numerical representations like “0.54”, “0.540302”, or “0.54030230587” are not exact but are only accurate within the respective number of digits. The fact that `cos(1)` is not simply translated to one of those numerical approximations is one of the features of SymPy, as it ensures that something like `simplify(acos(cos(1)))` actually yields `1` and not `0.99999999`.

That being said, there are of course purposes where you really need a numerical representation. In this case, you can use the class function `n` of SymPy expressions or the function `N` from SymPy, for example:

```
from sympy import cos, N
expr = cos(1)
print(expr.n())     # 0.540302305868140
print(N(expr))      # 0.540302305868140
```